# Get device location using android wear

Tags: android, gps, location, wear-os

I am trying to get my device location using an android wear application, but my app does not respond as it should.
I cannot understand why the system does not enter any of the OnLocationChanged, OnConnectionFailed and so on functions...
My guess is that it cannot connect to Google as it should but I am not sure about that. Any help is welcome, thanks!

```
public class MainWearActivity extends WearableActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setAmbientEnabled();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    // Connect to Google Play Services when the Activity starts
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        googleApiClient.connect();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "MainWear Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.arturo.pingutest/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    // Register as a listener when connected
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Use high accuracy
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 2 seconds
        locationRequest.setInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
        // Set the fastest update interval to 2 seconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
        // Set the minimum displacement
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(2);

        // Register listener using the LocationRequest object
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    // Disconnect from Google Play Services when the Activity stops
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "MainWear Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.arturo.pingutest/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.disconnect();
    }

    // Placeholders for required connection callbacks
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Display the latitude and longitude in the UI
        Log.d("PINGU", "Latitude:  " + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) +
                "\nLongitude:  " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

        Lat=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        Lon=String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />" in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these permissions in your app manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And add this code for triggering the request permissions activity:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},10);
```

The code above should replace this comment in you code

```
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
```